# Adding label to UIScrollView results in blank screen

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiscrollview

I'm trying to add a `UILabel`to my `UIScrollView`, but it doesn't show up at all. I've also tried adding a new `UIView` with red background color, which works just fine (scrolling and zooming both work).

I create my `UIScrollView`like this:

```
scrollView_ = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, screenW, screenH)];
[scrollView_ setBounces:YES];
[scrollView_ setMinimumZoomScale:1.0];
[scrollView_ setMaximumZoomScale:1.0];
[scrollView_ setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
```

and my `UILabel` like this:

```
aboutTextLabel_ = [[UILabel alloc] init];
aboutTextLabel_.numberOfLines = 0;
[aboutTextLabel_ setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"ChalkDust" size:11]];
[aboutTextLabel_ setTextColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
[aboutTextLabel_ setText:@"my text"];
[aboutTextLabel_ setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
[aboutTextLabel_ setFrame:CGRectMake(10,10,300,300)];
```

I then add it like this:

```
[scrollView_ addSubview:aboutTextLabel_];
[scrollView_ setContentSize:contentSize]; // precomputed
```

However, this gives me a blank screen. 
**When I create the aboutTextLabel as a local variable, the exact same code works.**

aboutTextLabel_ is not defined as a @property, but in the interface declaration.

Comment: Can you confirm screenW & screenH are set to what you want?

Comment: is aboutTextLabel_ is addSubview anywhere else?

Comment: How are you adding the scroll view to its superview?  Also what value are you using for contentSize.

Comment: @DavidC yes, they are correct.

Comment: @WarifAkhandRishi No, I don't add it somewhere else

Comment: @rdelmar I simply call `addSubview:` on the superview. Content size is the size of the `aboutTextLabel_` Please note: **The same code works if `aboutTextLabel_` is a local variable.**

Comment: I don't understand what's wrong -- I tried your code (using CGRectZero for the content size) and it work fine as written (it also worked defining aboutTextLabel as a local variable).

Comment: That is very strange indeed. I am using Xcode 4.2 with iOS SDK 5.1 on OS X 10.6.8. Cleaning the project/restarting Xcode/the computer didn't help... However, making the changes sunil z suggested, it seems to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

set `aboutTextLabel_.numberOfLines = 1;`

instead of

```
aboutTextLabel_.numberOfLines = 0;
```

Also add scrollView_ to the main view if you have not added like:-

```
[self.view addSubview: scrollView_];
```

Comment: setting the number of lines fixed it for me, thanks! Does anybody know why it works when I 
a) add the `aboutTextLabel` directly to the rootView
b) make `aboutTextLabel` a local variable
?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should not give label 'Text color ' as white...if your screen is already white...try adding a different color...or the default color 'black' will do..

Comment: The screen has a background image on it, changing the text color doesn't change anything.

Answer (score 0):

Change your label text color and add the label to your scroll view:

```
[aboutTextLabel_ setTextColor:[UIColor redColor]];

//add label to scrollView  
[self. scrollView_ addSubview:aboutTextLabel_];
```

Comment: Why would I do that? The code works just fine if I make `aboutTextLabel_` a local variable.

Comment: The problem is that I don't want a local variable, I want to store the pointer to `aboutTextLabel`.

Comment: That doesn't change anything. Why would it? `- init` is the first method that is called in the view lifecycle. I would think this is the best place to allocate and initialize instance variables.

Comment: If you want don't want local variable then you have to declare it globally..... that is in .h file.

Comment: That is obviously what I am doing atm. But, as stated in my question: The exact same code **works** if `aboutTextLabel_` is a local variable, and **doesn't work** if `aboutTextLabel_` is an instance variable.

Comment: as i was saying that alloc aboutTextLabel_ at proper place....it wil work for u...

Comment: and as I was saying, the `- init` method is the proper place to do so in my case. There is no difference when I allocate `aboutTextLabel_` in the `- viewDidLoad` method (tested).

Comment: ok then make a sample code of your problem..and send to me..then i will resolve it....